# Fetch api 10 times

Tags: javascript

I try to call an endpoint 10 times by wrapping a fetch call inside a for loop. But the results show one api call. So i was wondering if this wrong way doing it ?

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const apiCall = fetch('url')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(jsonResponse => {
    console.log(jsonResponse)
})

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    apiCall;
}
```

result:

```
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
```

expected results:

```
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
{ totalRecords: 0, totalPages: 0, page: 0, items: [] }
```

Comment: I bet you'd see the API call even without your entire loop at all. You're not even calling in your loop, but the call happens at line 2 already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop isn't doing what you think it is.

When you do :

```
const apiCall = fetch('...').then('...')
```

A request will be immediately made and `apiCall`  is a Promise returned by `fetch()`

What you probably want is to turn `apiCall` into a function and call that every iteration of the loop

```
const apiCall = () => fetch('...').then('...');

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    apiCall();// call the function
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It is the correct answer, *and* takes advantage of ES6!

Answer (score 0):

Set up a timer variable as a control and do your for loop within the api call.   Your code is not calling the loop

Answer (score 0):

The fetch is executed only once, during the assignment to const apiCall.

You should consider instead of using a const, making the call inside a function.

Something like that:

```
function apiCall(){
    fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonResponse => {
        console.log(jsonResponse)
});

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    apiCall();
}
```